# "true" evaluation running even when value is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean-expression

I have a very simple piece of jquery that needs to check a boolean value returned from an ajax call and set a checkbox to checked if it's true.

```
console.log("loc: " + r.location.defaultLocation);
if( r.location.defaultLocation == true ) {
    $('#loc-default').attr('checked',true);
}
```

This runs in an onclick function that opens a modal form - if the location info that is returned indicates that this is the default location, the checkbox should be checked. We have 5 of these on a single page - i.e. 5 locations the users can click on.

What I'm running into is that even if `r.location.defaultLocation` returns false (per the console.log line), the checkbox is still being checked. What am I doing wrong?

**For those of you who insist that true/false must be a string, rather than a boolean:**

This is the result of `console.info(typeof(r.location.defaultLocation));`

[image]

And this is the result of `console.dir(r)`, if it helps. (`group` is blurred because it's sensitive info.)

[image]

**FOUND THE ISSUE**

Apparently jquery is remembering that `#loc-default` is checked after the first one was marked checked. I added an else to the function and now it works:

```
if( r.location.defaultLocation == true ) {
    $('#loc-default').attr('checked',true);
}
else {
    $('#loc-default').attr('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: Just use `if( r.location.defaultLocation ) {`. Has nothing to do with your problem, but it annoys me when I see `== true` :P

Comment: And use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Comment: Are you sure `r.location.defaultLocation` is a boolean and not a string?

Comment: Is r.location.defaultLocation initialized? If so it is always true. What is the value of r.location.defaultLocation? You may want to test against that.

Comment: @Doorknob - I tried that first and got the same results, so I figured I'd go back to the full version to see if it made a difference.

Comment: @JamieHutber - no, as I said, this is the response from an ajax call.

Comment: @EmCo - yes, I tried doing a string compare instead of a boolean, and it didn't work at all. It's definitely boolean.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - the value of r.location.defaultLocation is either true or false - it's a boolean response. That's what I'm trying to test against.

Comment: How is it initialized @EmmyS? What is its value?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - it's the response from an ajax call. I don't know how much clearer I can be.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, why he should use `prop` instead of `attr`? What is the benefit?

Comment: Because prop() is aimed for use at things that or Boolean or fixed list in nature. It is the currently recommended practice by the jQuery team.

Comment: Actually `prop()` is for things where you'd use `elem.whatever` in plain DOM instead of `elem.setAttribute('whatever', ...)`. And disabled/selected/checked/readonly *are* accessed in the `elem.whatever` way.

Comment: Are you sure `$('#loc-default')` exists?

Comment: @Mottie - yes, I'm sure it exists. The problem is that `#loc-default` is being checked even when `r.location.defaultLocation` is false.

Comment: So, I'm guessing you have more than one `#loc-default`? The first one is the only one that will be modified, jQuery ignores all others.

Comment: @Mottie, no not really. The onclick event opens a single location in a modal dialog - the modal only contains one `#loc-default`. When you close one location and click on another, it opens the second location in the modal dialog. The problem is, if I have locations A, B, C, and D, and location C is the one that's listed as the default, when I open C in the modal dialog, the checkbox is checked. But it's also checked when I open any of the other locations in the dialog.

Comment: Well honestly, I think the next step would be to share your HTML or make a demo on jsFiddle.

Comment: @Mottie - look in the OP. I edited to add that I had found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code appears to be correct, I would try handling the else statement and force the checkbox to not be checked.

```
if( r.location.defaultLocation == true ) {
    $('#loc-default').attr('checked',true);
} else {
    $('#loc-default').attr('checked',false);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got your answer! Could you give Kenji here credit by checking his solution? :)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can see that happening is if defaultLocation is not actually the boolean false, but instead the string "false", which evaluates as true.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `r.location.defaultLocation` is a boolean.

Try `if (!!r.location.defaultLocation) {}` to force the value to be of type boolean.

Comment: The only problem is that `!!"false"` becomes `true`.

Comment: @Mottie doesn't `!!false` become `false`: i.e., `!(!false)` -> `!(true)` -> `false`?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar yes, but `"false"` is a string so `!!"anything"` will always be `true`

Answer (score 2):

I think `r.location.defaultLocation` is the **string** `"false"`. So if you use `console.log` on it, you will see `"false"`. But `"false" == true` is true.

You can check the type of a variable with `typeof`.

```
console.log(typeof r.location.defaultLocation); // Log the current type of r.location.defaultLocation
console.log(typeof false); // Display boolean
console.log(typeof "false"); // Display string
```

Comment: Wouldn't it log `"false"` ?, nevermind she is concating a String

Comment: It's not a string; I've tested for that. It's definitely a boolean true/false.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would check to see what `r.location.defaultLocation` is

```
 console.info(typeof(r.location.defaultLocation));
```

Then i would go from there but using above code:

```
 if (!!r.location.defaultLocation && typeof(r.location.defaultLocation)==="string") {}
```